# How to get a node value from xml based on another node value using perl

Tags: xml, perl

I have my `projects.xml` file as below:

```xml
<projects>
    <project>
        <id>ID_ABCD1</id>
        <name>ptest1</name>
    </project>
    <project>
        <id>IDB_abcd</id>
        <name>ptest1</name>
        <branch>bnm1</branch>
        <branched_from_id>ID_ABCD1</branched_from_id>
        <branched_from_version>111</branched_from_version>
    </project>
    <project>
        <id>ID_ABCD2</id>
        <name>ptest2</name>
    </project>
    <project>
        <id>IDB_abcd2</id>
        <name>ptest2</name>
        <branch>bnm2</branch>
        <branched_from_id>ID_ABCD2</branched_from_id>
        <branched_from_version>111</branched_from_version>
    </project>
</projects>
```

In my existing code I am getting project names based on project ID obtained from another file `categories.xml`.

For each of these project names I have to search is there any `branch` element for it, and if the element exists then I have to get 
the corresponding `branch` name and `branched_from_version`.

`branched_from_id` value is the ID of some other project.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;

use XML::LibXML;
use File::Basename;
use File::Find::Rule;
use XML::Twig;

my $cat_xml  = '/home/Ras/categories.xml';
my $twig     = XML::Twig->parse( $cat_xml );
my $doc      = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file( $cat_xml );

my $proj_xml = '/home/Ras/projects.xml';
my $twigp    = XML::LibXML->new->parse_file( $proj_xml );

my @nodes    = $doc->findnodes( '/categories/category' );

my $catname  = "/home/Ras/category.txt";

open FH, "> $catname" or warn "not able to open catname file";

foreach my $catnode ( @nodes ) {
    my @catn = $catnode->findvalue( '@name' );
    print FH "@catn \n";
}

my @catlist = `cat /home/Ras/category.txt`;

foreach my $cat ( @catlist ) {

    chomp( $cat );
    $cat =~ s/^\s+|\s$//g;

    my $path = "./category[\@name=\"$cat\"]/project";

    foreach my $project ( $twig->findnodes( "$path" ) ) {

        my $projout = $project->text;

        foreach my $projname ( $twigp->findvalue( "/projects/project[id = '$projout']/name" ) ) {

        }
    }
}
```

In above code `$projout` contain the ID value of my `project.xml` file. But those ID value with `branch` node are not there.

I have name value in `$projname`. So based on the name value in `$projname` I need to get the corresponding `branch` value and `branched_from_version` value.

Comment: Why are you mixing `XML::Twig` and `XML::LibXML`? That looks like a road to pain.

Comment: Can you clarify what the expected inputs and outputs are? Perhaps a [mcve] that we can run, with what the desired output would be?

Comment: This is a bit of a mess. You create a list of `category` names from `categories.xml` and write it to disk; then you read it back and search the same xml file for those `category` elements! You will need to show `categories.xml` as well if you want help with this.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit simplified, but I think you're trying to do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> parsefile ( 'test.xml' );
my $project = 'ptest2'; 

if ( $twig -> get_xpath("//project/name[string()=\"$project\"]" ) ) {
    print $twig -> get_xpath("//project/name[string()=\"$project\"]",0 ) -> text, " exists\n";
    foreach my $branch ( $twig -> get_xpath("//project/name[string()=\"$project\"]/../branched_from_id/..",0 ) ) {
       print "$project : ", $branch -> first_child_text('branched_from_id'), " => ", $branch -> first_child_text('branched_from_version'),"\n";
    }
}
```

I've had to cut it down, because I don't have your projects list. But this will use `XML::Twig`s `get_xpath` to find a project name - although note, it doesn't differentiate whether it's a branch or not for the first part of the check.

And then pulls out an `xpath` match based on this of all the branches that 'match'.